# Understanding BLOCKED_TIME in PerfView

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, threadpool, perfview, starvation

We are suspecting that we're experciencing thread pool starvation on a server that is running a couple of ASP.NET Core APIs and a couple of .NET Core consoles.

I ran perfview one one of our servers were we are suspecting problems with thread pool starvation. However I'm having a bit of trouble analyzing the results.

I ran `PerfView /threadTime collect` for about 60 seconds. And this is the result I got (I chose one to look at one of our ASP.NET Core APIs):

[image]

Looking at "By Name" we can see that there is a lot of time spent in `BLOCKED_TIME`. If I double click then I'm taken to the following view where I can expand one of the nodes to get the following view (the overwritten part is the name of our API process):

[image]

What does that tell me? Shouldn't I be able to see what exactly is blocking? And does it look like the problem is that a lot of threads is blocking each one for a small amount of time?

Are there any other conclusions we can draw from this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`BLOCKED_TIME` generally means a period when the thread wasn't doing anything at all. This could be periods of I/O, where network or other types of latency are involved or time spent waiting on locks such as in situations with semaphores. In short, this doesn't necessarily tell you anything, as there's perfectly standard and reasonable reasons for the thread to be idled. However, a goodish amount of time spent blocked can be an indication of an underlying problem. Perhaps you have too much network latency. Perhaps you're trying to do too much file system work on a slow drive. In short, it may or may not indicate a problem, and even if it does indicate a problem, it doesn't really tell you what the problem is.

In general, if you're experiencing thread starvation, the first thing you should look at is thread pool utilization. Are you using async everywhere you can? Are you doing things that are big no-nos in web apps such as using `Task.Run`, `Task.StartNew` or worse, `Thread.Start`? All those created threads are coming out of the same thread pool, and thus proportionally reducing your server throughput.

There's an all too common pattern of attempting to schedule long-running jobs by shuffling them to new threads. That's death to a web application. All threads in the pool are there to service requests, not long-running jobs, and as such, requests should be handled quickly and efficiently so that the thread can be returned to the pool in short order to field other requests. If you need to background work, you need to *truly* background it, by offloading to another process or even a different machine entirely.

Short of all that, maybe you're just getting more load than the server can handle in general. That's always a possibility. Perhaps you need to vertically scale your system resources (and the thread pool with it). Perhaps you need to horizontally scale by replicating this server with a load balancer in front. Given that you're running multiple different things on the same server, an easy way to horizontally scale is to simply divvy out these things to their own machines. That alone would probably help tremendously. However, scaling, either vertically or horizontally, should be your last resort. Make sure you're using resources efficiently first, before throwing more resources at your inefficient things.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to mention that the reason I was suspecting thread pool starvation was that I could see that roughly two ne threads were started every second, as mentioned in this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2018/10/16/diagnosing-net-core-threadpool-starvation-with-perfview-why-my-service-is-not-saturating-all-cores-or-seems-to-stall/. We’re not using Task.Run or anything like that, but I’d say that our IO is 50/50 using Async versus sync. For example ToListAsync vs ToList in Entity Framework

Comment: I guess what I was aiming for with my question was if I should be able to figure out which parts of the application were causing the BLOCKED_TIME. But maybe it’s just short periods of time all over the place that aggregate up to a large sum in total

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what it is. PerfView doesn't indicate what is causing the thread to idle, only that it is idle. If you want more detail, I'd suggest adding more extensive logging to your application, such that you can guage timing between various stages of what your code is doing.

Comment: > or worse, `Thread.Start`? - There's nothing wrong with `Thread.Start` and it has nothing to do with Thread Pool